# Count how many char in array numbers

Tags: php, arrays, strlen

I've an array got with preg_match_all.
This array contain 4 values and each value is a number.
I want to display ONLY the value that have 10 or more character.
Example:

```
Array_Value1 = 1234567890
Array_Value2 = 01234
Array_Value3 = 449125
Array_Value4 = 991234581210
```

I want to show with an echo only Array_Value1 and Array_Value4 because formed of 10 or more characters!
How can I do it?

I tried with `count_char` or `str_len` but I see a message that say "Array to String conversion".

Anyone can help me?

Comment: What's your array structure?

Comment: Loop through your array and do what you already did.

Comment: you have to cast to string before using strlen, see my answer!

Answer (score 2):

first of all you have to put all your values inside an array:

```
$array = array(1234567890, 01234, 449125, 991234581210);
```

after it you can use a simple foreach:

```
foreach($array as $value) {

if(strlen((string)$value) >= 10)
 echo $value;
}
```

you should add a separator after each echo, or you will have an output like

```
1234567890991234581210
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($values as $value)
{
    if (strlen((string)$value) >= 10)
        echo $value;
}
```

Comment: You'll have to accept one of the answers as accepted. So this topic can close. Since almost all of them are the same, it doesn't matter which one you'll mark.

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
foreach($my_arr as $val)
{
    if(strlen((string)$val) >=10)
       // more than or equal to 10
    else
       // less than 10
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
    $values = array(123123123, 53453453452345, 123, 9979797979797979);
    $string = implode(',',$values);
    preg_match_all('/(\d{10,})/', $string, $matches);
    print_r($matches[1]);
?>
```

Maybe it's more time-consuming... hehe